# Display item from nested ng-repat in bootstrap carousel

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question about how to choose a random item from a nested ng-repeat and set it to bootstrap carousel. Please see on my case:

```
var products = [{
  "title" : "First product",
  "comments" : [ 
    {
        "body" : "1 comment",
        "author" : "user 1",
    }, 
    {
        "body" : "2 comment",
        "author" : "user 2",
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title" : "Second product",
  "comments" : [ 
    {
        "body" : "1 comment",
        "author" : "user 3",
    }, 
    {
        "body" : "2 comment",
        "author" : "user 5",
    }
  ]
}
]
```

And html code

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products track by $index">  
   <div ng-repeat="comment in product.comments | limitTo: 1 | orderBy: main.random()" class="item {{::($index === 0 ? 'active' : '')}}"> 
      <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
      <p>{{comment.author}}</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Random function

```
$scope.random = function(){ 
    return 0.5 - Math.random(); 
};
```

Of course in real is more comments and products than in example but could you help me how display random comments in carousel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create a seperate function to get a single comment from random comments
- Display the randomly selected comment details in UI

Here the working code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {

      var app = angular.module("testApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
      app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.products = [{"title":"First product","comments":[{"body":"1 comment","author":"user 1"},{"body":"3 comment","author":"user 3"},{"body":"4 comment","author":"user 4"},{"body":"5 comment","author":"user 5"},{"body":"6 comment","author":"user 6"}]},{"title":"Second product","comments":[{"body":"7 comment","author":"user 7"},{"body":"7 comment","author":"user 8"}]}];
        $scope.getRandomComment = function(comments){
          return comments[Math.floor(Math.random()*comments.length)];
        };
      }]);
    }());
  </script>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products track by $index">  
      <div ng-init="product.randomComment = getRandomComment(product.comments)"> 
          <p>{{product.randomComment.body}}</p>
          <p>{{product.randomComment.author}}</p> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `ng-repeat` if you only have 1 element to loop through. So I'm assuming you want a function that can return several random elements.

You cannot use a filter though. AngularJS filters do not act like JavaScript's array [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, they just format the results.

But you can use a function that takes the array as argument and a number of random elements to return:

```js
angular.module('appModule', [])
  .controller('MyController', [function() {
    this.products = [{
        "title": "First product",
        "comments": [{
            "body": "1 comment",
            "author": "user 1",
          },
          {
            "body": "2 comment",
            "author": "user 2",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Second product",
        "comments": [{
            "body": "1 comment",
            "author": "user 3",
          },
          {
            "body": "2 comment",
            "author": "user 5",
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    this.randomPick = function(arr, qty) {
        return arr.sort(function(){
           return 0.5 - Math.random()
        }).slice(0, qty);
    }
  }])
  .filter('randomComment', function() {
    return function(arr) {
      var res = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
      console.log(res);
      console.log('***');
      return res;
    };
  });
angular.bootstrap(window.document, ['appModule'], {
  strictDi: true
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="product in myCtrl.products track by $index">
    <h2>{{product.title}}</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="comment in myCtrl.randomPick(product.comments, 1)" class="item {{::($index === 0 ? 'active' : '')}}">
      <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
      <p>{{comment.author}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very useful for me!